# Bash script with another command inside of quote

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, syntax

Trying to execute a command like

```
$ sdiff -i -W -B -l  -w 140 <(curl -s "https://domain.tld/query.php?d=$(date +%Y%m%d)") <(curl -s "https://domain.tld/query.php?d=$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y%m%d)")
```

I am trying to have the date automatically determined based on the `date`command .. the challenge here is that the command is inside of quotes inside of another command.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't immediately see why your command shouldn't work. What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Gentoo machine, running `sdiff (GNU diffutils) 3.7`, `sdiff` interprets `140` (from `-w 140`) as a separate argument. The correct invocation is this:

```sh
sdiff -i -W -B -l -w140 <(curl -s "https://domain.tld/query.php?d=$(date +%Y%m%d)") <(curl -s "https://domain.tld/query.php?d=$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y%m%d)")
```

Note that the options can be reduced a bit further:

```sh
sdiff -iWBlw140 <(curl -s "https://domain.tld/query.php?d=$(date +%Y%m%d)") <(curl -s "https://domain.tld/query.php?d=$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y%m%d)")
```

BTW: Try putting code between backticks (`) or triple-backticks next time.

Comment: Bingo! adding two `` did it! thank you! appreciated!